# generate one heatmap merging cuffdiff output from two experients (same control in both expts)

Tags: r, heatmap

I have two cuffdiff outputs - by comparing the same control against two different experimental conditions.
I was wondering about the best tool in R that can be used to make a clustered heatmap which can show all three conditions (control and 2 experimentals) in the same plot
thanks